# How to display gif loader till image is loaded in GridItem in android

Tags: android, gif, android-gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a GridView,I am setting images using my adapter,I have used Universal Image Loader library for loading images from the url,Now all is going good,But i want to put a gif loader to background of each grid item ,till the image in that particular gridItem is not loaded,can any buddy please suggest me how can i do this,My code is as below:

**adapter code**

```
package com.eps.fortalented.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.eps.fortalented.R;
import com.eps.fortalented.uc.GifWebView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class photosTalentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> photoArray;
    private Context mContext;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String photoImg;
    String query = "http://test.fortalented.com/manage/";
    Intent i;
    String camera, description, captured_date, date_modified, category,
            date_added, candidate_name, big_img;
    GifWebView view;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    public photosTalentAdapter(Context paramContext,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> photoList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.photoArray = photoList;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(paramContext));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.noimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).build();

        // New

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.photoArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_photo_talent,
                    paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.iv_photo = ((ImageView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_photo));
            localViewholder.rl_zoom = ((RelativeLayout) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rl_zoom));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(
                query + photoArray.get(paramInt).get("thumbnail"),
                localViewholder.iv_photo, options);

        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {

        ImageView iv_photo;
        RelativeLayout rl_zoom;

    }

}
```

Comment: Use Glide library (https://github.com/bumptech/glide), where u can download gif also, Its single line of code. try once integrating this library. it does lot of things

Comment: @HarshaVardhan-Thanks bro..I have gone thru your link,But not getting how to use it,can you give me some code or example demo like links for reference,Thank you